# Setting up a Destination Goal in Google Analytics using Regex

Tags: google-analytics, goals, regex

I want to set up a destination goal in GA to determine when a user reaches the end of a flow, or basically has completed a process.

The problem, the URL changes depending on the activity of the user so we have a URL like this (below) which can vary.

```
apply/UserAccount?execution=e1s2
```

The `S2` represents the last stage in the flow, which is the page I'm trying to capture. However the `e1` could be any number depending on the other activities of the user.

Can someone help with writing a Regex to make sure GA captures the every time a user reaches the last page regardless of the execution number? Is there a way to ignore the `E1` value and simply match the rest?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to allow the number to vary, even in its length. I would use:

```
apply/UserAccount\?execution=e\d+s2
```

Or in pieces:

`apply/UserAccount`

`\?`: escaped `?`

`execution=e`

`\d+`: one or more digits

`s2`